# Глагол "напортачить": стиль речи, этимология, способ образования

Tags: лексика

В словаре ненормативной лексики пометка - груб-прост. Также есть "просторечный" портач - нерадивый работник, халтурщик.

**Как образовалось слово:** портить - портачить? Но в в словаре словообразовательных частиц нет суффикса АЧИ.

**Можно  ли приличным людям грубо-просторечно выражаться?** Вроде бы выражаются: "Я не говорю уже о его обычных делах: о работе с артистами ...о заботах ― не напортачил ли механик, везущий тележку с аппаратом, не оговорился ли артист в дубле, не пропал ли настрой у исполнителей. [Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги (2000)].

**И когда, интересно, слово  появилось в языке,** оно совсем новое?

Comment: Возможно, "портачить" произошло от существительного "портач" (тот, кто портит).  Сравните со "стукач" (тот, кто стучит) или со "скрипач", которые не произвели своих собственных форм глагола.

Comment: А у меня это слово почему-то ассоциировалось со словом **портки**. (0:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, глагол был образован через существительное "портач": портачить - проявлять себя в работе как портач. Существительное же (встречается ещё у Ушакова, 1935) могло быть образовано от другого глагола, "портить".

Трюки выделывает трюкач, ловчит ловкач, портит портач, проталкивает дело толкач, тянет тягач и т.д.

На мой взгляд, в неформальной ситуации (например, в узком кругу коллег) слово "напортачить" (в отличие от слова "накосячить" уголовного происхождения) уместно и со стороны хорошо воспитанного человека; это способ назвать вещи своими именами. Слово "портач" употребляется сейчас крайне редко.

Comment: Да, наверное, портить-портач-портачить.  Только слово "портач" плохо выражает семантику глагола, должно быть,  поэтому оно практически ушло из языка.